# Trying to do screen mirroring of PC game on Android Phone using VR SDK. Image blinks

Tags: android, virtual-reality, screensharing, google-vr-sdk

I am trying to develop VR based Android app that does screen mirroring of PC with Counter Strike game to provide VR experience to player. I have installed VR SDK and using android studio for development. I have written following code for Screen mirroring on android , which shows blank frames in whenever a new frame is set on the phone. Can somebody help?

```
 Runnable takeScreenShot = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Options panoOptions = null;  
        panoOptions = new Options();
        panoOptions.inputType = Options.TYPE_MONO;
        String url = AndroidConstants.MAIN_URL();
        b = HttpView.drawable_from_url(url);
        if(b != null) {
            panoWidgetView.loadImageFromBitmap(b, panoOptions);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Have you checked out the preferences?

Comment: Do you mean  VR_OPTIONS ? I checked there are 2 options 1. Mono - for single image ( I am using this)  2. Stero OVER under means 2 images 1 below the other .. but it did not help. It still blinks.